# Plotting difference between a function and its inverse function

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction

I would like to plot the difference a function and its inverse function.

```
(1/27)*(x^4-6x^3+12x^2+19x) (* where 0<x<5 *)
```

I tried the following:

```
f = (1/27)*(#^4-6#^3+12#^2+19#) &;
g = InverseFunction[f]
Plot[f-g, {x, 0, 5}]
```

But it seems not work well.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f, g]
f = ConditionalExpression[(1/27)*(#^4 - 6 #^3 + 12 #^2 + 19 #),  0 <= # <= 5] &;
g = InverseFunction[f];

Grid[Partition[#, 2] &[Plot[#, {x, 0, #2}, PlotLabel -> #3, ImageSize -> 300] & @@@ 
    {{f[x], 5, "f[x]"}, {g[x], 10, "g[x]"},
     {{f[x], g[x]}, 5,  "{f[x], g[x]}"}, {f[x] - g[x], 5, "f[x]- g[x]"}}]]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also use `ParametricPlot` to plot `f`, `g` and `f-g`:

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, f[x]}, {f[x], x}, {x, f[x] - g[x]}}, {x, -1, 5},
 BaseStyle -> Thick, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> (c = {Red, Blue, Green}), 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[c, {"f[x]", "g[x]", "f[x]-g[x]"}, BaseStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: To plot f[x]-g[x] correctly, the third funcion of the ParameterPlot f[x]-x should be f[x]-g[x]?

Comment: @MS.Kim, you are right. Just updated the post with the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrating the problem with a simple example:

```
f = #^2 &;
g = InverseFunction[f];
```

> InverseFunction::ifun: Inverse functions are being used. Values may be lost for multivalued inverses.

```
g[f[3]]
```

> -3

As the message says, there may be multiple solutions.  Only one is returned.